# Calculate a sum on a range in column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I would like to calculate a sum on a range in column in panda dataframe in python.

Panda DataFrame:

```
acc     accname     amount
1010    turnover    10000
2000    salaries    -4000
3000    rent        -1500
5000    assets      15000
6000    liabilities -15000
```

I would like to calculate the result. `10000-4000-1500 =4500` or `sum(1010:3000)`.
And I would like to define the value as a variable called `result`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`pandas.DataFrame.set_index`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [**`pandas.DataFrame.loc`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) :

```
result = df.set_index('acc').loc[1010:3000, 'amount'].sum()
```

##### # Output :

```
print(result)
4500
```

Answer (score 1):

I am adding the whole data frame make and print to understand how its working

```
data = {'acc':[1010,2000,3000,5000,6000],
        'accname':['turnover','salaries','rent','asstes','liablities'],
        'amount':[10000,-4000,-1500,15000,-15000]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

You can use it simply by

```
result  = df['amount'].sum()
print(result)
```

output is:

```
4500
```

Comment: Thank you. The result is correct, but only because 5000 and 6000 sums to zero. I need a range in order to it make it work. I have received two solutions that solves that.

Answer (score 1):

Another option using a range of values for a certain column like this:

```
result = df[(df.acc >= 1010) & (df.acc <= 3000)]['amount'].sum()
```

Output:

```
4500
```

Comment: Good one! That will also be useful. Thanks.